# Laravel and Vue.js cannot see the css and js files

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I have my project written in Laravel + Vue.js. (It is not my project, but I have to improve it. I can not show code because I have NDA so i will only ask. It is API in laravel + front in laravel + vue. I committed that project, updated two .env's and installed it using:
composer update
npm install
php artisan serve

But there is problem because where I am on the page (127.0.0.1:8000) I see blank page. Here's some console:
[image]

When I am doing 127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js I see:
[image]

That doesn't works even when I have 777 chmod's on all project.

And command npm install every time says "114 installed 10 updated". Why this notice is not updating to 0?

Can u help me? What can I try?

Comment: is there any command prompt in laravel to install public files ?

Comment: I do not know. Probably not...

Comment: Did your run `npm run dev`?

Comment: @piscator yes. Many times

Comment: Does the page work without the JS and CSS included? Is the page root `localhost:8000/` ?

Comment: @apokryfos I can't see nothing without css and js. 
it is 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Have you perhaps defined a route that "catches" everything, something like `.*`? If that is the case, you should make it exclude assets.

Comment: @ThomasMoors can u explain me this?

Comment: An asset is also a route, if you match all routes, the assets will fail to load

Comment: @ThomasMoors Everything with code is okay. Before I had problems with permissions but now I don't know

Comment: You sure do overestimate your skills "SuperProgrammer" with " Everything with code is okay" You might want to try and learn a thing

Answer (score 0):

1. i thinks this is happening because you link to public/js/  is not right. try this.

   src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"

hope it helps.

i will be happy to see the web.php file also. thnx

Comment: @SuperProgrammer You can anonymize your code. Besides: If you post only the relevant code, nobody wants to steal this broken piece of code. we are here to help.